# Ubuntu and wine fullscreen issue

Tags: wine, workspaces

Hello this is my first post so I'm sorry if some of the formalities are missing.

I'm currently using Wine in order to launch games, WoW for example. The issue appears if I switch workspaces. If I do this, then the whole desktop is inoperable, I cannot use my mouse to select anything, I can only use my keyboard. If I exit my wine application, the issue remains until I re-log.

Thank you for reading and any help is good! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.10 on the WineHQ WoW 5.4 was rated as "Gold" and for other distributions it was rated as "Platinum" both mean that you will have almost no problems or any that make normal game play impossible.

The link is for the overall page for the game.
You can also add your own test results for which ever one you are using. But that is probably a bug, so if you go to this link.

http://bugs.winehq.org/

This is the page to submit a bug to Wine and see if anyone else has the same problem.
You will need an account to submit a bug.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28973

This the page for WoW. If you scroll down you will see a table titled "Known Bugs". If you think this is a WoW bug then enter a bug number (try any number above 36000) and it will get reviewed. (Note: First get an account just so that can give you an e-mail, so that can contact you.) Also may be helpful to post a comment at the bottom of the page.

You should try to post a bug at the Bugzilla, if all else fails then try the WoW page itself.

I hope this helped you!